# Политкорректность в русском языке

Tags: этикет

В Америке по какой-то причине слово "негр" для обозначения расы стало неполиткорректным. Хотя, признаться, не понимаю, почему: "negro" - "черный" и не более того. При этом "белый" оскорбительным не является.
Но у нас слово "негр" широко употребляется (что-то я не слышала, чтобы кому-то пришло в голову называть, например, студентов из Кении "афроамериканцами"))). Так вот, является ли в русском языке слово "негр" оскорбительным и, если да, то как называть представителей чернокожей расы, которые, если и "афро-", то совсем не "американцы"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы и сами знаете, что НЕ является. Но постановка вопроса - знаковая! В современном угаре американизации русского языка, вызванного глубоким комплексом провинциализма и плебейства, русские заимствуют у американцев не только слова, междометия, топонимику (что преступление для суверенитета), жесты, мимику, манеры, но и даже СМЫСЛЫ. Если киргизы стали называть КЫргЫзстан, значит и мы должны, если казахи - Алма-Аты, то и мы должны. Если у американцев "негр" - ругательное, то и у нас должно быть. Этого нет ни в одном уважающем себя языке, этого не было и в русском до эпохи Великого Падения. В КАЖДОЙ языковой системе действуют ЕЁ законы и правила, НЕВЗИРАЯ НА ДРУГИЕ ЯЗЫКИ, и задача любого переводчика (только не современного российского) переводить в реалии ДАННОГО языка.

Comment: Первая  часть  вашего  высказывания  бред  -  нет  никакого  угара  американизации  русского  языка.  Во  второй  части  вы  правы - в  каждой  языковой  системе  действуют  её  законы  и  правила.

Comment: В рамках данной логики киргизы - американский народ.

Comment: Разъясните,  пожалуйста.

Comment: @bernard Не видеть стремительной американизации русского языка может только глухой, слепой или лицемер, который прикрывает свои интересы подобной близорукостью (как мадам Эмма Володарская). Сейчас, если составить список убитых русских слов за последние 15-20 лет - не хватить страницы А4. Причем это не новые явления, типа пресловутого "компьютер", а простые тысячелетние слова, которыми русские стали брезговать. (Если интересно - напишу подборочку.) Про КЫргЫзстан подробно обсуждалось на вопросе про "Беларуский". Русские последние 20 лет особенно преклоняются перед иностранными словами.

Comment: @bernard В первую очередь - американизмами, но и всё остальное тоже "круче", чем родные старинные названия. "Бред" или невежество у Вас в голове и ещё у 9% населения Вам подобных: согласно последним опросам, 75% россиян возмущены американизацией русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

В русском не является. Более того, в русском скорее "чёрный" является словом "с намёком".

Comment: Конечно.  У  нас  ведь  негров  не  было.  А  у  американцев  были  -  рабами.

Comment: Угу. Никакого исторического стыда перед неграми у нас нет. Кроме того, именно "чёрными" называют некоторых других людей, да и само слово имеет негативную окраску (тёмный, злой, таинственный, неискренний).

Answer (score 1):

Вы историю учтите, кто был рабами, кто неграми, кто хозяевами, белыми.
И значение этих терминов в прошлом.
"Проблемы негра шерифа не волнуют" - слышали? Думаю смысл ясен.
И полагаю не слишком было бы приятно звучало
"Думы/чаяния ватника/укропа/славяна арийца не тревожат"

Comment: "Думы негра арийца не тревожат" - это ж для КОГО звучит НЕ ПРИЯТНО??? Ну, да - скоро на вашем амерашине будет: "Айдиэсы африканоса шерифа не трабалуют"

Comment: Господин школьник, будьте добры, не оффтопьте, Вам же четко-ясно ответили, не в состоянии осмыслить - промолчите.

P.S. "Вашем" - с большой буквы пишется.

Comment: На всякий случай — на письме писать "Вашем" с большой буквы считается стилистически неверным, если это не официальное обращение (повышенный уровень подчёркнутого уважения) или анкета (адресат неконретен — любой "Вы", который будет ей пользоваться). Прописная буква также ставится, если слово попало в начало предложения. Как обычно.

Comment: @N3ver_Again "господин школьник" - это Вы мне?

Answer (score 0):

Формально не является, на деле является. Чем заменять, не могу сказать, не знаю.

Comment: Значит, вскоре появится соответствующий эвфемизм. Который, в свою очередь, тоже со временем станет оскорбительным.

"Жид" до революции означало просто "еврей". Сейчас это слово почему-то считается оскорблением. Хотя даже если человека спросить "Вы еврей?", он тоже выглядит оскорблённым. Причём вне зависимости от того, положительным или отрицательным является в ответ на этот вопрос в его случае.